# Preservation of parallel lines is equivalent to preservation of collinearity?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

When I read a matrix algebra textbook, it says this.

I know the preservation of parallel lines implies the preservation of collinearity, but how can I prove the inverse?

Comment: Among which class of maps? Maps from a vector space to itself that preserve lines?

Comment: @Travis Maps from a vector space to a vector space that preserves the parallel lines.